# Typescript Type of multiple enums

Tags: typescript, enums

I have multiple enums in my app

```
enum HondaModels {
   Accord = 'Accord',
   ...
}
enum ToytaModels {
   Camry = 'Camry',
   ...
}
```

In my code I check if a car model passed to me is a Honda or Toyota.

I would like to declare a type that is either HondaModels or ToyotaModels

If i try this, I get an error

```
 type modelTypes: HondaModels || ToyotaModels
```

is there a better approach to having a custom type that is one of multiple enums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would also avoid String enums. Using discriminated unions is much better because enums are strongly typed.

```ts
const HondaModels = {
  Accord: "Accord",
} as const;
type HondaModels = typeof HondaModels[keyof typeof HondaModels];

const ToyotaModels = {
  Camry: "Camry",
} as const;
type ToyotaModels = typeof ToyotaModels[keyof typeof ToyotaModels];

type modelTypes = HondaModels | ToyotaModels;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error

```js
enum HondaModels {
   Accord = 'Accord',
}
enum ToytaModels {
   Camry = 'Camry',
}

type modelTypes =  typeof HondaModels | typeof ToytaModels

// Then use it like this
let abc: modelTypes = HondaModels
```

thanks to [Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) for the improved solution

Comment: Thank you for your response; I'm actually looking to store abc as all HondaModels or ToyotaModels, of NissanModels, etc.

```
let abc = HondaModels
```
this returns an error

Comment: @RaySaudlach, for that latter, you need the union to be a union of the types of the enumerations, not their members: `type modelTypes = typeof HondaModels | typeof ToytaModels
`